# HTML DOM. anyway to get attributes dict?

Tags: javascript

node.attributes  return a NamedNodeMap..
and it won't give out all the attributes names or values like in the xml.

is there a way get something like this?

`node.attributes.keys`

`node.attributes.values`

`node.attributes.items`

any kind ?

now I use this for my won use..But js won't give out the attributes names like class、id、href.it gives number instead..

```
listattr = function(node) {
    var attrs = [[],[]];
    for (var attr in node.attributes) {
        if (node.attributes[attr].nodeValue) {
            console.log(attr);
            console.log(node.attributes[attr].nodeValue);
            attrs[0].push(attr);
            attrs[1].push(node.attributes[attr].nodeValue);
        }
    }
    return attrs;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> But js won't give out the attributes names like class

It is an array-like list of [Attribute nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr), which do have values and names! You are logging the indices.

```
var attrs = node.attributes;
for (var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++)
    console.log(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s answer basically says it all, but here's a complete function (using underscore) to convert an html element's attributes to a dict:

```
_.reduce(myElement.attributes, function(memo, element){
  memo[element.name] = element.value;
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
Array.from(node.attributes).reduce((acc, it) => ({ ...acc, [it.name]: it.value }), {})
```